# Creating a .net tcp server

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm an amateur programmer working on a pet project of mine and I would like some pointers on how to make a C# server application. Here's the general idea:

A client connects to the server application, which in turn fetches the necessary information from a mysql database and sends it back to the client to be displayed and wait for the next action.

I got the idea of making something like this after seeing a somewhat old IBM AS400 mainframe running a warehouse management system, and I though: "Hey, I could try developing a small version of this with a nice UI that doesn't look like it stepped out of a time machine!"

I searched around and used the `tcplistener` class to communicate between the server and client and managed to send some calls and responses using one thread per client. However I've read that this is not scalable for a large number of clients...

Am I looking at this problem the wrong way and I should try something else? Any input will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried looking at WCF to handle your messages rather than dealing with TCP directly?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with TCP directly for this - WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) was written to abstract all the low level stuff from you.

Check this link out for a good example of how to create a client/server application, it has an entry level explanation, some code and a downloadable project...
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16765/WCF-Windows-Communication-Foundation-Example

You can find plenty of information about WCF elsewhere on the internet and here on SO.

It is a very large topic, but the situation you have described is pretty simple - so I doubt you will have problems following the example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Currenty writing a server architecture and came across this as well: faily easy to solve.

You're right, using 1 thread per client is not effiecient and is a huge waste or resources! The way around that is **Thread Pooling**. There are loads of different ways to do this but the way I chose to implement it on my server was to add every connection to a queue and then have x number of threads (which you can easily increase or decrease to handle demand) simply dequeue a connection, process it, then enqueue it again.

Of course using WCF will make life easier for you and will speed things up drastically but where's the challange in that!